# Why is Curve25519 in the GPG “expert” options?

Tags: elliptic-curves, pgp

The only way to access the Curve25519 curve in GPG is through `gpg --expert --full-gen-key`.

From my knowledge, Curve25519 is one of the most secure (and fast) elliptic curves in cryptography. So why is RSA fine, but Curve25519 is considered a risk only experts should take?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The risk mainly resides in compatibility.

See, not all GPG users/systems are updated to the latest version. If you look at the GPG changelogs, you'll notice [ECC was first introduced to GPG with version 2.1](https://www.gnupg.org/faq/whats-new-in-2.1.html) in 2015:

> - Support for Elliptic Curve Cryptography (ECC) is now available. ⇒[more](https://www.gnupg.org/faq/whats-new-in-2.1.html#ecc)

None of the pre v2.1 versions of GPG support ECC, which is something that can and most probably will cause several annoyances and interoperability issues — hence the *"expert"* toggle which can be interpreted as *"herewith I confirm that I know what I'm doing and that I'm aware of related compatibility problems that may come within it"*.

Note that this is only an annoyance for the time being; things will surely brighten up while time goes by and more users/systems adopt newer GPG versions by updating

Also note the related dependencies and — last but not least — the OpenPGP specification "draft" status, which additionally influence adoption speed:

> **Encryption ECDH — RFC7748: Curve25519**
>
> OpenPGP specification: [RFC4880bis draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-openpgp-rfc4880bis)
>
> Dependencies:
>
> - libgcrypt >= 1.7.0
> - Gnuk >= 1.2.0

(Source: https://wiki.gnupg.org/ECC)

Comment: That draft is only for Curve25519. 3 NIST ECC curves are already in [RFC 6637](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6637) according to the Wiki page you cite.

Answer (score 3):

Support for what GnuPG calls `cv25519` public-key encryption keys, and for `ed25519` public-key signature keys, is neither standardized nor widespread, so you're likely to hit compatibility issues with anyone else using OpenPGP.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: I noticed in my **Proton Mail** account that my keys use **ECC** (**Curve25519**).
So, a simple way to use this encryption method is with a fellow Proton Mail user.